# how do i extract only the records with all email entries missing

Tags: mysql, group-by, max, having, sql-null

I have a question so I have this table:

```
| Manager_Name | Email_Address |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| person A     |Email@email.com|
| person A     |Null|
| person A     |Null|
| person A     |Email@email.com|
| person A     |Email@email.com|
| person B     |Null|
| person B     |Null|
| person B     |Null|
| person B     |Null|
| person B     |Null|
| person C     |Email@email.com|
| person C     |Email@email.com|
| person C     |Email@email.com|
| person C     |Email@email.com|
| person C     |Email@email.com|
| person D     |Null|
| person D     |Null|
| person D     |Null|
| person D     |Null|
| person D     |Null|
```

My question is how do I extract only the the managers that have all the 5 email addresses missing like person B and person D, in the original table I have a lot of them I want to get only them with all 5 addresses missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `Manager_Name` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Manager_Name
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Manager_Name
HAVING MAX(Email_Address) IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fc7b2d482f2eadd3a1f0c9e33c990d4).

Comment: This still gave me all the managers that have a null in their email records

Comment: @SoufianeBenounssi then you are doing something wrong because the query works fine. See the demo I added in my nswer.

Comment: My bad LOL, I certainly was doing it wrong hahaa now it works thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table a WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM table b 
    WHERE a.Manager_Name = b.Manager_Name AND Email_Address IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: I only have one table

Comment: correct, they are both the same table with a different alias name.